# Why is System.Windows.Shape.Path sealed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inheritance, extension-methods

I was trying to extend the shape class to contain an additional variable but have found the class is sealed. How can I achive this simply, using an alternate implementation approach?

Is creating a new class and storing a shape an passing all the method calls through the easiest approach; I'm sure there is a better way though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF has a powerful concept named **Attached Properties**. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but perhaps you can solve your problem by using this concept. To provide an exampe, the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties are properties attached to elements inside a `Grid`.

```
<Grid>
  ...
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ... />
</Grid>
```

The `TextBlock` class is unaware of the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties used by the `Grid`.

You can read more about [attached properties on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Comment: I should have been slightly more specific; in this instance the variable is an object, so I don't think this will work, good suggestion though

Comment: How would this approach not work? An attached property can be of any type.

Comment: I went with a slightly different approach and just created a new object which stored the reference to the path and the reference to the other object I needed to link to. I'm sure this can be done in a more elegant way but seems to work OK for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

If the variable you want to add is one which you would only ever be reading from, and is calculated as a result of other members of the Path class, you could add an extension method which would return your value.

However, if this is not the case:

Consider creating a class which inherits from Path's parent - Shape, which is not sealed.
Then add a private Path member to this. You can grab all the shape method calls for free and would only have to provide wrappers for the unique members of Path.